# Terminal Stuck Loading GatsbyJS "Hello-World" starter website

Tags: terminal, gatsby

I've been moving step-by-step (as a webdev newbie) through the GatsbyJS installation via the Terminal. All looked great, except the Terminal appears "stuck" and I'm not sure how to resolve (i.e. whether to close Terminal app or let the process continue). It's been over an hour without any change in the Terminal prompt. Please see screenshot for detailed info. Any help would be much appreciated.

screenshot: Current state of Terminal app:

[image: screenshot: Current state of Terminal app]

screenshot: Message when trying to close Terminal app:

[image: screenshot: Message when trying to close Terminal app]

Comment: `gatsby develop` starts up a development server that watches for changes in your code and makes the build available in your browser. So while you are working, you should leave it running. Press `ctrl+c` in your terminal when you want to stop the `gatsby develop` command, then you can close your terminal without that prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Your terminal is not stuck. Everything works as it should.

It is listening to code changes which enables hot reloading. This way you can change code and you see the changes almost instantly in your browser. This makes for a pleasant developer experience and is industry standard.

Beware the old times when you had to manually restart your server everytime you made the tiniest code change.

Try opening a browser with url `http://localhost:8000`. Change some text inside your index.js. You should see it reload in the browser.